# Aggregation functions returns AttributeError: 'Sum' object has no attribute 'lookup'

Tags: django, django-queryset

I'm trying out the aggregation functions, and I get this strange results (latest official Django 1.2 release).
Here's the model:

```
class Reputation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    modifier = models.IntegerField()
    activity = models.ForeignKey(Activity)
```

This is what I get:

```
In [37]: Reputation.objects.aggregate(r=Sum('modifier'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

C:\Data\Development\django_projects\oko\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.pyc in aggregate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    142
    143     def aggregate(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 144         return self.get_query_set().aggregate(*args, **kwargs)
    145
    146     def annotate(self, *args, **kwargs):

C:\Data\Development\django_projects\oko\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.pyc in aggregate(self, *args, **kwargs)
    315         for (alias, aggregate_expr) in kwargs.items():
    316             query.add_aggregate(aggregate_expr, self.model, alias,
--> 317                 is_summary=True)
    318
    319         return query.get_aggregation(using=self.db)

C:\Data\Development\django_projects\oko\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.pyc in add_aggregate(self, aggregate, model, alias, is_summary)
    929         """
    930         opts = model._meta
--> 931         field_list = aggregate.lookup.split(LOOKUP_SEP)
    932         if len(field_list) == 1 and aggregate.lookup in self.aggregates:
    933             # Aggregate is over an annotation

AttributeError: 'Sum' object has no attribute 'lookup'
```

Comment: Where have you imported `Sum` from?

Comment: Good question; see my answer, below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Judging by the fact that your post is the sole mention of that error message via google searching, and that I can reproduce your error by using a random class called `Sum` into an aggregation function, I think you have a local definition of `Sum` in your code.

You're on line 37 of your console session. Try starting anew, `from django.db.models import Sum`, `from myproject.myapp.models import Reputation`, then the query.

Comment: Ohh, I didn't about that. I'm sure this will help people googling!

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you import the correct `Sum`:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
```

If you import `django.db.models.sql.aggregates.Sum`, you will continue to see that error.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error by failing to include the aggregation function within an annotation i.e.

wrong:

```
Person.objects.annotate(ave_score='starred_in__score')
```

right:

```
Person.objects.annotate(ave_score=Avg('starred_in__score'))
```

A stupid mistake on my part, but thought I'd document it here in case it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what the question is about, but I encountered almost the same error (no attribute 'lookup') using `F` in `annotate`. The import was correct, but [its use in `annotate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/) was added in Django 1.8 whilst I am using Django 1.7. You’d need to use [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#using-f-expressions-in-filters) instead if you’re also using that old Django release.